# A faster alternative to all(a(:,i)==a,1) in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, boolean, comparison-operators

It is a straightforward question: Is there a faster alternative to `all(a(:,i)==a,1)` in MATLAB?

I'm thinking of a implementation that benefits from short-circuit evaluations in the whole process. I mean, `all()` definitely benefits from short-circuit evaluations but `a(:,i)==a` doesn't.

I tried the following code,

```
% example for the input matrix

m = 3;       % m and n aren't necessarily equal to those values.
n = 5000;    % It's only possible to know in advance that 'm' << 'n'.

a = randi([0,5],m,n); % the maximum value of 'a' isn't necessarily equal to 
                      % 5 but it's possible to state that every element in 
                      % 'a' is a positive integer.

% all, equal solution

tic
for i = 1:n % stepping up the elapsed time in orders of magnitude
    %%%%%%%%%% all and equal solution %%%%%%%%%
    ax_boo = all(a(:,i)==a,1);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
end
toc

% alternative solution

tic
for i = 1:n % stepping up the elapsed time in orders of magnitude
    %%%%%%%%%%% alternative solution %%%%%%%%%%%
    ax_boo = a(1,i) == a(1,:);
    for k = 2:m
        ax_boo(ax_boo) = a(k,i) == a(k,ax_boo);
    end
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
end
toc
```

but it's intuitive that any "for-loop-solution" within the MATLAB environment will be naturally slower. I'm wondering if there is a MATLAB built-in function written in a faster language.

EDIT:

After running more tests I found out that the implicit expansion does have a performance impact in evaluating `a(:,i)==a`. If the matrix `a` has more than one row, `all(repmat(a(:,i),[1,n])==a,1)` may be faster than `all(a(:,i)==a,1)` depending on the number of columns (`n`). For `n=5000` repmat explicit expansion has proved to be faster.

But I think that a generalization of Kenneth Boyd's answer is the "ultimate solution" if all elements of `a` are positive integers. Instead of dealing with `a` (`m` x `n` matrix) in its original form, I will store and deal with `adec` (`1` x `n` matrix):

```
exps = ((0):(m-1)).';
base = max(a,[],[1,2]) + 1;
adec = sum( a .* base.^exps , 1 );
```

In other words, each column will be encoded to one integer. And of course `adec(i)==adec` is faster than `all(a(:,i)==a,1)`.

EDIT 2:

I forgot to mention that `adec` approach has a functional limitation. At best, storing `adec` as uint64, the following inequality must hold `base^m < 2^64 + 1`.

Comment: What is this supposed to evaluate? Are you looking for columns that are identical to column `i`?

Comment: And if that is the case, it’s equivalent to just evaluating if they are all identical to column 1. No need to loop over them.

Comment: Cris Luengo, yes, I'm looking for all columns that are identical to a given column of the same matrix.

Comment: horchler, I'm not sure if I got your point. Are you talking about the "i-loop"? It's there for benchmarking purposes only.

Comment: In this case, the number of elements in each column is very small, meaning that there are only 8 possible unique columns. I would find out which columns are equal to each of the 8 possibilities rather than matches for each of the 5 columns using something like `b=([4 2 1]*a==[0:7].').'`, which seems to be 3 or 4 orders of magnitude faster in Octave. But, of course, changing the input sizes could have a drastic effect on the speed difference.

Comment: beaker, the presented `a` matrix was just an example. I only know two things about `a` in advance: (i) "`m` << `n` but `m` can be as high as 20; (ii) `a` has only positive integer elements that can be as high as 50.

Comment: Could you clarify the role of `ax_boo` after that? There may be no need to compute `ax_boo` at all.

Comment: rahnema1, `ax_boo` isolates the indices of the columns I have to sum in a row vector `b`. So, basically the next line would be something like c = sum(b(ax_boo),2);.

Comment: I will update my answer based on your clarification. Could you update your question adding that comment?

Comment: That’s precisely why I chose to leave a comment rather than an answer. It was obvious that you had not given us the details necessary to provide a relevant answer. All of the information in your comment should be in the question itself.

Comment: beaker, I'm glad you are trying to help me out but my question was a very specific one. I asked about `all(a(:,i)==a,1)`. More information is only needed to give a different approach to my problem.

Comment: Hmmm @Zalnd, that "ultimate solution" looks familiar... But I thought you didn't want a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your goal is to count the number of columns that match, my example converts the binary encoding to integer decimals, then you just loop over the possible values (with 3 rows that are 8 possible values) and count the number of matches.

```
a_dec = 2.^(0:(m-1)) * a;
num_poss_values = 2 ^ m;
num_matches = zeros(num_poss_values, 1);
for i = 1:num_poss_values
   num_matches(i) = sum(a_dec == (i - 1));
end
```

On my computer, using 2020a, Here are the execution times for your first 2 options and the code above:

```
Elapsed time is 0.246623 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.553173 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000289 seconds.
```

So my code is 853 times faster!

I wrote my code so it will work with `m` being an arbitrary integer.

The `num_matches` variable contains the number of columns that add up to 0, 1, 2, ...7 when converted to a decimal.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can use the third output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html):

```
[~, ~, iu] = unique(a.', 'rows');

for i = 1:n
  ax_boo = iu(i) == iu;
end
```

As indicated in a comment:

> `ax_boo` isolates the indices of the columns I have to sum in a row vector `b`. So, basically the next line would be something like `c = sum(b(ax_boo),2);`

It is a typical usage of [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~, ~, iu] = unique(a.', 'rows');
C = accumarray(iu,b);
for i = 1:n
  c = C(i);
end
```

Comment: As I stated before, the `i-loop` is there for benchmarking purposes only. It's there only to step up the elapsed time in orders of magnitude. In fact, I did use `unique` for the cases I know I must to check every column and not only a few. But for the matter of the original question, I don't need to check all the columns. I was pretty sure that calling unique in that context would be slower, but I will check here. Finally, about `accumarray`, it is a valid alternative to my original approach. Thank you.